# Linux recursive permission inheritance

Tags: permissions, chmod, chown

I am wanting to allow file/folder permission inheritance.

On my machine, I want some directories to belong to some user/group. This is achieved by running: `sudo chown my_user:my_group my_directory`. A whole group is directly working on code within this directory. However, when a specific user *user_a* belonging to group *my_group* creates a new file within this directory, the permissions on this file are automatically set to *user_a:user_a* but I would like these permissions to be set to *user_a:my_group* or to *my_user:my_group*. I was able to achieve this by setting the gid/uid in the following way `sudo chmod g+s my_directory`. However, this will not work for any file/directory within a newly created directory.

I have struggle achieving this and I therefore believe there is a good reason this is not easily handled by Linux, why ?

Comment: What do you mean with _"However, this will not work for any file/directory within a newly created directory."_? If the setgid bit is set on the directory, then any new file and directory created within it should copy the group owner from the containing directory, _and_ any directory created should also get the setgid bit. That's how it works on my system anyway. Can you [edit] your post to show exactly what you tried and what happens for you?